# как узнать количество ссылок на объект в java

Tags: java

вопрос как можно получить количество ссылок на экземпляр объекта или хотя бы больше 1 ли их.

Comment: Java не хранит информацию о количестве ссылок (другие языки зачастую используют именно счетчики ссылок для сборки мусора, однако такой подход не учитывает циклические зависимости). Если у вас есть ссылка на объект, то одна ссылка уже точно есть; также вы можете использовать WeakReference, который позволит вам в нужный момент определить, что объект точно собран сборщиком мусора (хотя тот момент, когда исчезнет последняя ссылка на объект, может произойти гораздо раньше).

Comment: Вопрос довольно интересный, но все же можно узнать зачем Вам это понадобилось?

Comment: В java есть метод `finalize`, который вызывается перед разрушением объекта (когда нет ссылок на него). Но никто не даёт вам гарантии, в каком потоке будет вызван этот метод, да и вообще, никаких других гарантий не даёт... Как вариант, вы можете в методе finalize складывать ogl-объекты в какой-то пулл, после чего в главном потоке проходиться по нему и все удалять. Но я не рекомендую так делать, лучше удаляйте все вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, исходная задача ниже

> я пишу программу с использованием openGL и так как сборщик мусора не
>   работает в видео памяти мне самому нужно решать удалять ли например
>   текстуру из видео памяти

В этом случае есть стандартный подход, который рекомендуется Java:

1. Всё то, что в Native - оборачиваете в Wrapper, который реализует [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).
2. Работа с объектами, реализующим этот интерфейс - через [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
3. В обертке дополнительно создаете метод [finalize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) метод, который вызовет сама Java, когда убедится, что наш объект может быть удален из памяти. Здесь надо очистить объект, если он не был очищен ранее в пункте 2.

Насчет счетчика ссылок - в Java нет никаких легких и быстрых способов определить, сколько объектов ссылаются на ваш, так как если бы он был:

1. Обновление счетчика ссылок должно быть строго атомарным (у нас же многопоточное приложение?)
2. Отсюда следует, что почти каждое получение объекта требует атомарной операции (ну т.е. все процессоры и все ядра должны отработать строго синхронно). Например, когда вы делаете `someObject.getSomeData().toString()` вы должны кучу раз атомарно изменить счетчик ссылок.

Пункты выше радикально снизят производительность любой программы на Java. Это одна из причин присутствия Garbage Collector'а, кстати.

Однако раз формально вопрос был про число ссылок на объект, приведу алгоритм его получения:

1. Как я описал выше, сначала необходимо сделать Full GC (он приведет к полной остановке программы на небольшой время)
2. С помощью приложений, аналогичных [этому](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html) ([тут](https://habr.com/company/dbtc/blog/322950/) есть тоже неплохой обзор), можно проанализировать граф зависимостей, который составил Garbage Collector.
3. В графе можно найти текущий объект (т.к. граф будет содержать ссылку на него), а далее найти всех, кто на него ссылается.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать статическую переменную класса, и при создании экземпляра объекта увеличивать эту переменную на 1.

Comment: а когда уменьшать?